# Sorting a dictionary by its value in descending order and its key in ascending order

Tags: python, sorting

I'm tasked to extract all unique characters in a string (excluding whitespace) and sorting it based on the amount of appearances of a given character in the string (so in descending sort order) and in case of ties, sort by their ASCII code.

Example:

> Input: 'I am a cat'
>
> Output: 'aIcmt'

The problem I'm facing particularly is the fact that if I use this line of code for sorting:

`char_list = sorted(char_dict.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1],ord(x[0])), reverse = True)`

It reverse sort even the `ord(x[0])` which sorts the `char` part of the dictionary though I only want to sort the value of occurences of the characters.

Here is my code for references:

```
string_list = [char for char in string]
string_list = [char for char in string_list if char != ' ']

print(string_list)

char_dict = {}

for char in string_list:
    if char not in char_dict:
        char_dict[char] = 0
    else:
        char_dict[char] += 1

char_list = sorted(char_dict.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1],ord(x[0])), reverse = True)
print(char_list)

for i in char_list:
    print(i[0], end = '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try combination of `Counter`, `sorted`, and `join`.

```
from collections import Counter

input_str = 'I am a cat'

# use counter to get count of each character including white space
t = list(Counter(input_str).most_common())

# sort on count on reverse and ascii on ascending when ties 
t = sorted(t, key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0])) 

# exclude white space and join remaining sorted characters
res = ''.join(i[0] for i in t if i[0] != ' ') 

print(res)
```

Output:

```
aIcmt
```

Comment: Oh you got it, I've just replaced my `(x[1],ord(x[0])), reverse = True` by your `(-x[1], x[0])`. Didn't know that I could reverse sort by putting a negative sign. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) takes an iterable (strings are iterable and will return each character one at a time when iterated over) and will return a dictionary-like object from which you can get each entry sorted by the number of occurrences using `most_common`

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(string)
print(''.join(x[0] for x in counter.most_common()))
```

EDIT:

As Mad Physicist says, to exclude spaces from being counted you can pass a generator to Counter

```
counter = Counter(c for c in string if c != ' ')
```

Comment: `Counter(c for c in string if c != ' ')`

Comment: How does this handle ties of count? From OP, `in case of ties, sort by their ASCII code`.

Comment: @student since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict` from Python 3.6 onwards it will return the character that occurs first in the string before any other character that occurs the same number of time

Comment: @student so you're correct I have not fully answered the question

Answer (score -2):

are you allowed to do this task without the use of dictionary? if yes you could try this way : use a counter for every letter, them check the chars of the string without the space, adding a counter(use a switch) to the letter that matches, after that compose a string beggining with "" them add letters that have more than 0 counters(you could either sort the int values of the counters to do it in order or check before adding wich position the letter will go, sorting is probably easier) after that you will have what you want.

Comment: Why would you not use a dictionary for this?

Comment: no reason not to, but if you don't have a reason to use, that's a way of doing it without it